# Multiple, Dynamic, Sidebars Problem - First Sidebar not working properly

Tags: functions, sidebar

This is my function:

```
function ec_register_sidebars() { 
register_sidebars( 3, 
    array( 
    'name' => 'Sidebar %d', 
    'id' => "sidebar-$i", 
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">', 
    'after_widget' => '</li>', 
    'before_title' => '', 
    'after_title' => '' 
    ) 
);
```

This **does not work**:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'Sidebar 1' ) ) : ?> 
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar 1' ); ?> 
    <?php else : ?> 
    No primary sidebar content 
<?php endif; ?>
```

**BUT** if I change the *is_active_sidebar* to 'Sidebar 2' or 'Sidebar 3', it works. For example, **this works**:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'Sidebar 2' ) ) : ?> 
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar 1' ); ?> 
    <?php else : ?> 
    No primary sidebar content 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't understand why this is.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your name attribute is missing the sprintf aspect. that line should read

```
'name' => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ),
```

otherwise %d doesn't reference $i at all. Also, it looks like you should be calling the sidebar id, not the name. The name is just for looks. For example, once the above is fixed, this coould work:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
```

Comment: It's still not working.  Here is a url with a text file that comprises all the code involved: http://estevancarlos.kodingen.com/ecv7/ec_code.txt

Here is an active page: http://estevancarlos.kodingen.com/ecv7/?projects=rada-2

Comment: You should not check the active sidebar by the index number, then activate it with the slug id. use one or the other. ie.  <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>i would simplify the whole thing. also, don't generate all three sidebars in that one loop. add the three individually without the variables and %1$s complexity. look in the twentyten or twentyeleven theme and just copy exactly how they do it and modify it for your own.